# Flask webservice https call results in ssl error

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, flask, python-requests

I have Flask based webservice providing REST interfaces.

We have written webservice class inherited from `flask.Flask` and can't provide entire the code here but webservice app call looks like,
`app.run(host=host, port=port, ssl_context='adhoc)`

With this when I try to run GET request then I am getting SSL error,

```
  File "/opt/debesys/build/x86-64/debug/python/tt/pyrate/test/test_juno_sim.py", line 1077, in test_main_page
    resp = requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers, verify=False)
  File "/opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/debesys/ext/linux/x86-64/release/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 382, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

I have also tried starting app like,
`app.run(host=host, port=port, ssl_context=('cert.pem', 'key.pem'))`
Also used `urllib2` module for get request instead of `requests` module.

But getting same error. If I try starting app without `ssl_context` and use `http` then getting response successfully.

Here I am using `headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` and `url = "https://127.0.0.1:{}".format(port)`

```
[shrishinde@localhost debesys]$ wget https://127.0.0.1:47855/
--2020-02-19 13:03:25--  https://127.0.0.1:47855/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:47855... connected.
OpenSSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Unable to establish SSL connection.
[shrishinde@localhost debesys]$ wget http://127.0.0.1:47855/
--2020-02-19 13:03:28--  http://127.0.0.1:47855/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:47855... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 31 [text/html]
Saving to: “index.html”

100%[=====================================================================================================================================================================>] 31          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2020-02-19 13:03:28 (6.25 MB/s) - “index.html” saved [31/31]

[shrishinde@localhost debesys]$
```

**Update**

***Found solution:***
After inheriting Flask, we have overridden Flask `run` method and in that `WSGIServer` is used so instead of `ssl_context` I should use [ssl_args](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.wrap_socket).

With hope that above steps will help user diagnose similar issues so keeping the question.

Answer (score 2):

I might know what's happening, even though you should provide part of the code alongside the stack trace to better understanding of the problem.

> SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

This error is produced when OpenSSL receives a wrong parameter in the Handshake from the server. It might happen if the server is answering with plain HTTP (withouth TLS). It might happen for other various reasons, your client might not understand the TLS version (library only supports SSL) or something like that.

Try to run the request with `wget`or `Postman` to the url (http://your.url:422). If you get a response, SSL is not enabled.

**Fixed**

Ok i've managed to replicate your problem, you aren't running the server in ssl mode. Run this.

> pip install pyopenssl
>
> python -m flask run --cert=adhoc

And ensure that the message is running ont https://127.0.0.1:5000/ and then quit it and run it with

> > python -m flask run --cert=adhoc -p [your port]

To run int in your desired port

Comment: Your guess is correct. wget with http is successful. Can you please suggest as solution?

Comment: Ok, I don't know if you are in development mode or production mode. If you are in development try this https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https if not you might need to enable it in your Apache/Nginx or other web server.

Comment: Please tell me if this is the correct solution to include it in the main response.

Comment: I am in development  mode and had referred this same blog and thats why tried with pem files as well in ssl_context

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot that part, let me check something.

Comment: And when you do a request to https://127.0.0.1:47855 what's the response?

Comment: it's the exact response I am returning from my REST interface.

Comment: Check the last part of the main response and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks @lucferbux for all the help. It's my fault. After inheriting Flask, we have overridden run method and in that WSGIServer is used so instead of ssl_context I should use ssl_args. So this question is not valid. I will delete it today.

Answer (score 1):

Without the code it is only possible to guess.

Since the error states `unknown protocol`, you might want to check if you're calling the correct protocol, eg. not calling `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP`, which is a common mistake when developing on your local environment.